# cv2.cv module not found in OpenCV for Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to do use some of the constants in the cv2.cv module like this:

```
fps = videoCapture.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

However, the cv2.cv module doesn't seem to exist and I cannot import it in any other way. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if that's opencv 2.4.8 - true. the cv2.cv module is no more available.

the constant you're looking for is: cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS